# Make NLTK tokenizer ignore capitalization

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I need to split some  text sections into sentences and I'm using the NLTK tokenizer for this purpose. These text pieces are all lower-case and in general of low quality, making it more difficult. However, it's okay with a few errors from time to time as long as the general rules of the language is upheld. For instance, I want the sentences to be split after a dot. The text sections may contain many individual sentences as well as abbreviations etc.

How do I ensure that NLTK ignores capitalization and splits the text below into 2 sentences between "2006." and "though"?

```
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize

print sent_tokenize('no drop in its quality as it got nearer to its end, in 2006. though i didn\'t like the movie much.')
>> ["no drop in its quality as it got nearer to its end, in 2006. though i didn't like the movie much."]
```

Comment: You should be able to convert the string to lowercase or uppercase and then tokenize it

Comment: This might be a use-case for training your own sentence tokenizer

Comment: http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html#module-nltk.tokenize.punkt
The `sent_tokenizer` is actually a wrapper around a pre-built English Punkt sentence tokenizer, anyway. You can train your own, though. It's unsupervised, to boot!

Comment: Thanks. How big a corpus does it need to be effective?

Comment: I guess if you're only dealing with that specific issue, you could just capitalize all `"\w"` characters that follow a `"\.\s+"` string with a regex. training your own tokenizer is way more legit though!